# Gradle Dependency Management: latest.integration vs. latest.release

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I just came across a small question concerning Gradle's dependency management.
I know that I can declare dependencies using `latest.integration` to reference snapshots or use `latest.release` to reference artifacts from release builds.

My question is:
Does `latest.integration` exclusively and only refer the latest SNAPSHOT artifacts or will `latest.integration` resolve using a release artifact, if the latest release artefact has a higher version than the latest from integration?

Example:

```
latest snapshot artifact: 2.1
latest release artifact: 2.2
```

If using `latest.integration`, which one will be used to resolve the dependency?
If its the case that `latest.integration` also integrates release artifacts, by which rule can I explicitly refer to snapshot artifacts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`latest.integration` resolves to latest snapshot or release, whichever is newer. There is no symbolic version for latest snapshot only (use `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT`).

Comment: Note that these magic versions identifiers only work for dependencies, not for plugins.